# select from three tables with one common id

Tags: sql, database

I have three tables, and they have the same Id which is the `AccountId`

my tables:

```
account
-AccountId

loandetails
-LoanDetailsID
-AccountId
-commission
-date


employee
-EmployeeID
-AccountId
-Team
```

I want to display their commissions that are group by the different team and together with the different date. Any help will be much appreciated, or please point out if I have any error in my tables.

Comment: Is it correct that an Employee can be linked to only **one** Account? This seems odd if you're modeling activity in a lending institution. I would expect an Employee could be linked to multiple Accounts--but maybe the entities do not mean what I think they mean.

Comment: each of the employees will have a unique account

Comment: @John.J, can you share the code you have tried, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be like this:

```
SELECT employee.team,
       loandetails.date,
       loandetails.commission
FROM account
INNER JOIN loandetails ON loandetails.AccountId = account.AccountId 
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.AccountId = account.AccountId 
GROUP BY 
       employee.team,
       loandetails.date,
       loandetails.commission
```

Check it, and let me know result. I hope to be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

select a.commission from loandetails a inner join employee b on a.AccountId = b.AccountId group by b.team, a.date

Answer (score -1):

You can try this example, but it will also depend in what do you want to select from the three tables

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM (
    (Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
    INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
);
```

this example is from